# Call pytest from a python script with an argument

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytest, python-3.7, python-dataclasses

Project structure:

```
/prj_root
   |
   |___some_test.py
   |
   |___main.py
```

I have the following test written in `pytest`:

`some_test.py`:

```
def test_something(entty):
    #Some pytest code
```

and the following script

`main.py`:

```
@dataclass
class Entity(object):
    name: str

if __name__=='__main__':
    entity = Entity(name = 'some_stub_value')
    #Here I want to invoke pytest's test_something test method
    #with entity passed as an argument
```

**Is there a way to pass argument to `pytest`'s test method from a python script?**

Answer (score 1):

I just mixed something up and tried this:

**testing.py**

```
def test_something(entty):
    print(entty.name)
```

**testing2.py**

```
from testing import test_something

class Entity(object):
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

if __name__=='__main__':
    entity = Entity(name = 'some_stub_value')
    test_something(entity)
```

Does this help you? :)